# How to specify a profile photo url when creating a Wordpress user via the json api

Tags: php, wordpress

When using the Wordpress api to create a user (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) is there a way to specify a profile photo / avatar?

I don't want the standard gravatar to be displayed. I want to specify a photo url.

Here is the example code:

```
$user_id = username_exists( $user_name );
if ( !$user_id and email_exists($user_email) == false ) {
    $random_password = wp_generate_password( $length=12, $include_standard_special_chars=false );
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $random_password, $user_email );
} else {
    $random_password = __('User already exists.  Password inherited.');
}
```

Comment: I think that you'd have to create your own custom setting for user image, or use 3rd party plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordpress has no feature to add custom image for the user. There are two way to display profile image:

**1. Avatar:** to change the avator, you should go `Settings > Discussion` section of wordpress admin panel. Scroll down at bottom, you can see there are few default options of avator.

**2. Gravatar:** to use `Gravator` image in user profile, you should sign up at `https://en.gravatar.com`. Wordpress automatically grabs the image if sign up email address matches with 'Gravator' email.

**Solution for you:**

When you create user, you can add the image's url as meta field to the user. See the following example:

```
$user_name = 'userid';
$user_email = 'user_email@domain.com';
$user_id = username_exists( $user_name ); // check if user exist

if ( !$user_id and email_exists($user_email) == false ) { // if user does not exist

   $random_password = wp_generate_password( $length=12, $include_standard_special_chars=false );  // generate random password

   $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $random_password, $user_email );  // creating new user

   $img_url = 'http://orig15.deviantart.net/9faa/f/2011/006/e/9/there__s_something_about_molly_by_avator-d36l074.jpg'; // this is a sample image url but you should add the image url from json api 

   add_user_meta( $user_id, '_user_img_url', $img_url); // save the image url as meta field where meta key is _user_img_url

  } else {

      $random_password = __('User already exists.  Password inherited.');

  }
```

Now the question is, how you will retrieve image url:

```
// assume that the user id is 6
$user_id = 6; 
// met key what we used to create user
$key = '_user_img_url';
// If true return value of meta data field
$single = true;
// get the image url
$user_img_url = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );
```

So, now you should `echo` the image url in `html` image tag:

```
<img src="<?=$user_img_url; ?>" alt=""/>
```

Hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The previous two answers did not work for me. Instead, I only got success with this:

```
$gallery_image_id = 1234; // Replace this with ID of your uploaded image
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_user_avatar', $gallery_image_id); // This should be correct if your WordPress tables were set up with the standard 'wp_' prefix. If you set them up with, say, a 'wp_mysite_' prefix then you'll need to change 'wp_user_avatar' to 'wp_mysite_user_avatar'.
```

This means you will need to upload the image to the media gallery first - and then use the ID of that image as the `$gallery_image_id` value, in the above snippet.

Also, not sure if this is theme-dependent, but I only got the image to show once I had added a `user_email` (e.g., something@example.org) to the user data.

Please also note the second comment in my code snippet, above, as it is very important! :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can manually set avatar for user with using [wp_insert_attachent](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment). You should use this steps:

1) Download image to `wp_upload_dir` because second parameter of `wp_insert_attachent` `$filename` is:

> Location of the file on the server. Use absolute path and not the URI
>   of the file. The file MUST be on the uploads directory

2) Create attachment with `wp_insert_attachent`

3) Attach avatar to user with `update_user_meta`

So code can be something like this (I long ago wrote nothing for us wordpress, so maybe this code does not work immediately, so that may need some refinement):

```
// url for user avatar
$imageUrl = '...';
$user_id = username_exists( $user_name );
if ( !$user_id and email_exists($user_email) == false ) {

    $random_password = wp_generate_password(
        $length=12, $include_standard_special_chars=false );

    $user_id = wp_create_user(
        $user_name, $random_password, $user_email );

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    // Download file by url and save it
    // to our file system into $upload_dir
    $file = $upload_dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$user_id.
        'avatar_'.basename($imageUrl);
    copy($imageUrl, $file);

    // Create attachment
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($file), null);
    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $upload_dir['url'] .
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($file),
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file)),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file);
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file);
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);

    // Attach avatar to user
    delete_metadata('post', null, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar',
        $user_id, true);
    update_user_meta($user_id, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar', $attach_id);
    update_user_meta($user_id,
        $wpdb->get_blog_prefix($blog_id) . 'user_avatar', $attach_id);

} else {
    $random_password = __('User already exists.  Password inherited.');
}
```